# Azure: Is there a way to view deployed files in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a file "view" available in Azure?

When I log in to Azure to look at a website I've deployed there is no obvious see exactly what files Azure is hosting.

---

I can see there's the Visual Studio Online option which allows you to live edit your server code but that is more than I need.  I just want to be able to check that certain files are deployed and others are not.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

If you're just trying to look around, and see the various directories and files in your deployment, you can enter the site's "Kudu" dashboard, using the url format `http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net`

This will give you a web-based dashboard, including a debug console (web-based) where you can explore your various directories (and the directories will show up visually as well).

More info can be found in [this post from the Azure Websites team](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/).

Comment: Up to date infos under [Kudu Wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki).

Comment: http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/ is what I was ultimately looking for.

Answer (score 109):

In Visual Studio, in the window "Server Explorer" you click and connect on "Azure".

=> App Service

=> Your site name

=> Files

Here you see all your files and you can edit them directly in Visual Studio.

[image: Edit File on Azure]

---

### @@@@@ UPDATE 19/08/2019 @@@@@

For some time now, it hasn't worked anymore.... :(

Here is another way to do it: By FTP !

From the Azure portal, in the "App Service" section of your website, go to "Deployment Center" > FTP > Dashboard

There is the FTPS Endpoint => ftp://.....ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot

And username, password information.

Install FileZilla Client! (https://filezilla-project.org/)

Enter Host with "FTPS Endpoint" the "username" and "password" and then login quickly!

Comment: The easiest way for me!

Comment: Strange that there isn't a way, at all, without either having VS or learning some other app, to just see the content.

I had cloned an app and got a notice via the dashboard that something went wrong so thought it didn't clone at all.  Only when I logged in later did I see that the clone DID happen and wanted to scope the files out, etc.

Sure enough, VS does the trick.

Comment: Great answer. And for those who would look around for Username/Password to connect the FTP server, they can be found into the AppService > YourApp > Deployment Center > FTP tab. They are different from Azure base credentials.

Comment: Thanks ! With "Deployment Center" it's easier ! I update my post^^

Comment: See "yu yang Jian"'s answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385985/115704 - for a Visual Studio alternative.

Comment: FTP is what is needed if you are interested in viewing the files

Comment: Solved for me. Just needed to be able to browse files, etc. Very surprised with how amazing Azure is that I'm finding myself back to using Filezilla which I haven't needed to use for 10 years or so.

Answer (score 58):

You can use **App Service Editor** (previously known as *Visual Studio Online*). It can be found under your webapp -> Development Tools section in the Azure Portal.

Comment: The App service editor option is removed from app service development tools section

Answer (score 52):

I know this is old, but I just found it, and got some useful tips from it. If you are using an App Service, there is now a browser option to do this as well:

https://YourAppService.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/

You can get there from the Azure portal, then go to your App service, then scroll down to Development Tools, and click on "App Service Editor".

[image]

Comment: So simple. Love it

Comment: For me just located at: https://YourAppService.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/ 
Or you can just go to https://YourAppService.scm.azurewebsites.net/ and see everything that is available.

Answer (score 7):

In VS2017/2019, there's Cloud Explorer to view files in Azure, but each time open folder to view files will invoke connection to cloud, so you have to wait, that's a bit slow.

To open Cloud Explore, `Right click on project > Publish > Manage in Cloud Explore`, or `Top Menu > View > Cloud Explorer`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That could be relevant: AppService->Console
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have many options to see that

1. By clicking Console option (run "dir" command, will list down all files)
2. By hitting App Service Editor(Preview) option,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the accepted answer,
you can open an ssh session by going to `http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host`.

For a long time, I've looked for a linux-style terminal to view my deployed files and environment variables. With this you can view the files, check and set environment variables, make db migrations directly, and a lot more. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux AppService, type **/NewUi** after `http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and then go to `File Manager`

[image]
,

Sometimes Kudu may show only these options in the UI.

[image]

If you only see these menu options then type **/NewUI** at the end of this URL `http://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and then go to `File Manager`

Comment: Just a note. NewUI works for Linux app services only. More detail is available [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/new-kudu-ui-for-app-service-on-linux-preview/ba-p/3212270).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code and the Azure extension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well if this helps at this year.
I need to check the log files that my api creates so I use the FTP account that you already have enable with username and password, just follow the next steps:

1. Go to Azure account
2. App Services (I suppose you have there your published code)
3. Click over the app you want to get/check files
4. Under "Deployment" at your left, select "Deployment Center"
5. At your right select then "FTPS Credentials"
6. Just copy the FTPS Endpoint, username and password
7. Connect to your app folder from FTP Client like FileZilla

that will be enough to get your files and check any changes or whatever you want.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a connection problem while publishing an application service to Azure from behind my employer’s firewall. Here is the complete error message:

```
Error 1 Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer [...]). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)
```

This is obviously a showstopper that hinders you from getting your site published to the public cloud from your employer’s company domain. Fear not though, as there is a solution to this; by disabling SCM. The solution is based on an answer from Patrick McCurley at StackOverflow:

```
Go to the Azure Portal.
Click on App Services.
Click on your application service.
Click on Application settings.
Scroll down to Application settings.
Click Add new setting, and add the following entry:
```

Name: WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM, Value: false

```
Click on Save and close the Application settings window.
Click on your application service.
Download the publish profile by clicking on Get publish profile.
Import the publish profile when publishing your application service to Azure from Visual Studio.
```

This effectively disables SCM and enables you to publish your application service to Azure.

Comment: Thus is what helped me when other results didn't

Answer (score -1):

browse to https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI

Answer (score -4):

Since you are using Azure Websites, Azure wants to "manage" it for you, and as a result, you cannot connect to the VM itself. If you were using a Cloud Service, you can obtain the RDP information from the Azure Console and just remote into the machine.

For your situation, you can use FTP as an option. Here is blog that describes one approach:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx

Here is another option using WebMatrix: 
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-edit-a-site-hosted-on-windows-azure-with-webmatrix

Comment: This is actually not accurate, as I explained in my answer: You can connect to an Azure Web App via kudu and access the file system.