# Can we uplaod image file using Kudu to my website dir deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have deployed my website on Azure and can view the deployed content using Kudu as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382334/is-there-a-way-to-view-deployed-files-in-azure). I can even create folder and text files in any directory of my deployed website using this interface. I don't see a way to upload my image file here. Is it possible somehow without redeploying my website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can easily upload a folder, file or image by dragging and dropping with Kudu console to deployed website directory .

[image]

Comment: That's easier than I was thinking. Thanks