# can notepad++ edit Azure website source files directly?

Tags: notepad++, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, editing

Is it possible to  edit azure website source files with notepad++?

i tried to open a link like this:

https://somazuresite.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/index.aspx

I get a windows security message that says "connecting to azure" and prompting me for my user and password but it does not accept it . just keeps prompting.

Comment: You can edit a file on azure directly from Visual Studio, there is this method => https://stackoverflow.com/a/43963725/2736742

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to edit azure website source files with notepad++?

I used the [NppFTP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) plugin for Notepad++ to connect with the ftp server of my azure web app.

[image]

Choose your file and modify it, then save your modification, then the modification would be automatically uploaded to your web app ftp server. For retrieving the ftp host name and your credential, you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191234/where-is-download-publish-profile-in-the-new-azure-portal/34191267).

Moreover, you could just use the Azure App Service Editor to edit your web content. Details you could follow [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).